# Icomoon - can i use the icomoon chrome plugin to generate icon-fonts without any licensing ?

Tags: css, fonts, icons

Am developing web application for the public use(could be banking or retail). can i generate my required icons with ico-moon generator without any license or do i need to pay and get license to use??
Please help me to understand on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a link to the license of each icon pack in the library tab of IcoMoon: https://icomoon.io/app/#/select/library

If you're using your own icons, you don't need any licenses.